# View is not updated after scope chance

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS app with a simple view :

```
<span ng-repeat="answer in question.answers">
  <hr>
  <small>By <a href="#">{{answer.author}}</a> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> Posted on {{answer.date | date:'medium'}}
  </small>
  <p class="lead" ng-bind-html="answer.content"></p>
</span>
```

and the controller :

```
$scope.submitAnswer = function() {
  var email = UserCredentials.getEmail();
  Questions.answer($scope.question._id, $scope.answer.message, email).$promise.then(function(response) {
    $scope.question = response.data.question;
  });
}
```

but when I when I call this function, the view is not updated. Still, if I log `$scope.question`, it has the updated value... only the HTML is not updated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
Angular.copy(response.data.question, $scope.question)
```

instead of your assignment code

```
$scope.question = response.data.question;
```

This will update the object and trigger a digest, thus updating the view.

Comment: this wouldn't work..the already wrap the code in `$promise` .then function, and how come `angular.copy` will run digest cycle..?

Comment: True, the copy method will not trigger the digest cycle, the updated scope object will, because the object will change from it's last state. The copy method creates a deep copy of the source object.

Comment: I don't understand. what is need of `angular.copy` there.. digest cycle is already going to be taken care by `$resource` promise on `.then` function of it..